# How do I calculate a point on a ellipse’s circumference?

Tags: math, java-me, geometry, ellipse

I want to plot a point in elliptical curve in J2ME

I have values for X,Y,width,height and t.

**X** and **Y** are the position of the ellipse(according to J2ME) with respect to  Canvas and  **t** is angle with respect to the center of ellipse(I have an image representation of the problem , but unfortunate blog is not allowing to insert into discussion :) )

```
int ePX = (X + width)+ (int) (width * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(t)));
int ePY = (Y + height)+ (int) (height * -Math.sin(Math.toRadians(t)));
```

Is this equation correct? or for ellipse do we need to have some more calculations?

Answer (score 12):

If ( X, Y ) is the center of the ellipse, and width and height are the two axes, then the equation should be

```
int ePX = X + (int) (width  * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(t)));
int ePY = Y + (int) (height * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(t)));
```

The -1 multiplication to Math.sin is unnecessary if you have all `t` to draw the entire ellipse.

Comment: @Nguyen: Sorry I think you're mistaken. AFAIK,  `( aCos( \th ), bSin( \th ) )` parameterizes an ellipse, and when `( a == b )` it becomes a circle. Here `a := width` and `b := height`.