# Eyes following cursor - positioning?

Tags: javascript, cursor

I'm trying to create a thing that follows the mouse round the page using Javascript. I want it to be Mickey Mouse and I want his eyes to move around the his eyeballs following the mouse... This is the code I have so far (gathered from places all over the web so credit to whoever wrote what part):

```
<script>
var jseyesimg="http://oi67.tinypic.com/frnys.jpg";
var jseyeimg="http://oi63.tinypic.com/nxwa5u.jpg";
var jseyeslink="http://www.javascriptkit.com";

var jseyeso=null, jseye1=null, jseye2=null;
var standardbody=(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat")? document.documentElement : document.body //create reference to common "body" across doctypes

function jseyesobj(id) {
var i, x;
x= document[id];
if (!x && document.getElementById) x= document.getElementById(id);
for (i=0; !x && i<document.forms.length; i++) x= document.forms[i][id];
return(x);
}

function jseyesmove(x, y) {
var ex, ey, dx, dy;
if (jseyeso && jseye1 && jseye2 && jseyeso.style) {
ex=jseyeso.offsetLeft+46; ey=jseyeso.offsetTop+58;
dx=x-ex; dy=y-ey;
r=(dx*dx/49+dy*dy/289<1) ? 1 : Math.sqrt(49*289/(dx*dx*289+dy*dy*49));
jseye1.style.left= r*dx+36.5+'px'; jseye1.style.top= r*dy+44+'px';
ex+=56; dx-=56;
r=(dx*dx/49+dy*dy/289<1) ? 1 : Math.sqrt(49*289/(dx*dx*289+dy*dy*49));
jseye2.style.left= r*dx+92.5+'px'; jseye2.style.top= r*dy+44+'px';
}
}

function jseyes() {
var img;
var x, y, a=false;

if (arguments.length==2) {
x= arguments[0];
y= arguments[1];
a= true;
}

img= "<div id='jseyeslayer' style='position:"+
       (a ? "absolute; left:"+x+"; top:"+y : "relative")+
       "; z-index:5; width:150; height:150 overflow:hidden'>"+
     "<div id='jseye1' style='position:absolute; left:130; top:44; z-index:6; width:21; height:29'>"+
       "<img src='"+jseyeimg+"' width=21 height=29 onClick=\"location.href='"+jseyeslink+"'\">"+
     "</div>"+
     "<div id='jseye2' style='position:absolute; left:160; top:44; z-index:6; width:21; height:29'>"+
       "<img src='"+jseyeimg+"' width=21 height=29 onClick=\"location.href='"+jseyeslink+"'\">"+
     "</div>"+
     "<img src='"+jseyesimg+"' width=300 height=300 onClick=\"location.href='"+jseyeslink+"'\">"+
 "</div>";
document.write(img);
jseyeso=jseyesobj('jseyeslayer');
jseye1=jseyesobj('jseye1');
jseye2=jseyesobj('jseye2');

document.onmousemove=jseyesmousemove;
}

function jseyesmousemove(e) {
    var mousex=(e)? e.pageX : event.clientX+standardbody.scrollLeft
    var mousey=(e)? e.pageY : event.clientY+standardbody.scrollTop
jseyesmove(mousex, mousey);
//return(false);
}
</script>
```

I can't figure out how to get the eyes to be placed within they eyeballs. If anyone could tell me what values mean what I'd like to trial a few figures to see what looks best. :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally think using canvas for something like this makes more sense.

I've created an annotated example below.  The example doesn't use images so you'll have to work that part out yourself, a good resource for information on the canvas API (including how to draw images) [can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

The mathematics can be broken down as:

1. Calculate the angle between the mouse and the center of the eye
2. Use trigonometry to find the point on the circumference of the eye at that angle.  The maths is very slightly complicated by the fact that mickeys eyes are ellipses and not perfect circles, so their radius changes depending on the angle.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9412217/997127) for more details.
3. Minus the radius of the pupil (use trig from point 2 again as radius changes depending on angle).

*Note: press "Run code snippet" to see the example work.*

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const TWOPI = 2 * Math.PI;

// size the canvas to the full width/height available
// Note: this solution is not responsive
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

// eye objects will be in charge of holding state and rendering themselves
class Eye {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 40;
    this.height = 80;
    this.pupil = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20 };
  }

  draw() {
    const {x, y} = this;
    
    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    
    this.drawOutline();
    this.drawPupil()
    
    context.restore();
  }
  
  drawOutline() {
    const {width, height} = this;
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.ellipse(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, TWOPI);
    context.stroke();
  }
  
  drawPupil() {
    const {x, y, width, height} = this.pupil;
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.ellipse(x, y, width, height, 0, 0, TWOPI);
    context.fill();
  }
  
  track(object) {
    const {x, y, width, height, pupil} = this;
    // find the angle between the mouse and the center of the eye
    const xDiff = (x - object.x);  
    const yDiff = (y - object.y);
    const angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) - Math.PI;

    if (!isNaN(angle)) {
      // calculate the point on the circumference of the eye
      const cX = (width * Math.cos(angle));
      const cY = (height * Math.sin(angle));
      // calculate the point on the circumference of the pupil
      const pX = pupil.width * Math.cos(angle);
      const pY = pupil.height * Math.sin(angle);
    
      //  position the pupil at the edge of the eye, minus the radius of the pupil
      pupil.x = cX - pX;
      pupil.y = cY - pY;
    }
  }
}

// on mousemove update the mouse position
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
});

const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const leftEye = new Eye(100, 100);
const rightEye = new Eye(200, 100);

// on every tick redraw the eyes with a new position
function tick() {
  // clear canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // track the mouse and draw the left eye
  leftEye.track(mouse);
  leftEye.draw();
  
  // copy the state of the left eyes pupil
  rightEye.pupil.x = leftEye.pupil.x;
  rightEye.pupil.y = leftEye.pupil.y;
  //rightEye.track(mouse); // or use this for independent eye tracking
  rightEye.draw();
 
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

// kick off animation loop
tick();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<canvas />
```

If you are interested in visual programming I think you would learn a lot by looking into [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) and the [work of Daniel Shiffman](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman); he has a plethora of videos on getting started with stuff just like this.  I hope this helped, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Would there be any way to put these eyes on top of an image in the right place? I'm absolutely awful at programming and feel like that would be easier! :D

Comment: The only way to get better at programming is to experiment so I'm leaving this to you I'm afraid!  

To point you in  the right direction; using the canvas API you can draw the image of Mickey onto the canvas before the eyes, see this page on MDN for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images.  Alternatively you could position the `<canvas>` element with the eyes over an HTML `<img>` element using CSS.

Comment: i've been working on it for the past hour or so, and I think I'm slowly figuring it out. thank you very much for your help :)